# cassandra dies on ubuntu right after it is started

Tags: cassandra

I have installed latest cassandra on ubuntu following instructions at http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/install/installDeb_t.html

Installation went without errors, but cassandra dies right after it is started. The output is below. Would someone please help me?

`$ cassandra -f
INFO  21:42:17 Hostname: e2execdatadev1
INFO  21:42:17 Loading settings from file:/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
INFO  21:42:18 Node configuration:[authenticator=AllowAllAuthenticator; authorizer=AllowAllAuthorizer; auto_snapshot=true; batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb=5; batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb=1024; cas_contention_timeout_in_ms=1000; client_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; cluster_name=Test Cluster; column_index_size_in_kb=64; commit_failure_policy=stop; commitlog_directory=/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog; commitlog_segment_size_in_mb=32; commitlog_sync=periodic; commitlog_sync_period_in_ms=10000; compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec=16; concurrent_counter_writes=32; concurrent_reads=32; concurrent_writes=32; counter_cache_save_period=7200; counter_cache_size_in_mb=null; counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; cross_node_timeout=false; data_file_directories=[/var/lib/cassandra/data]; disk_failure_policy=stop; dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold=0.1; dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms=600000; dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms=100; endpoint_snitch=SimpleSnitch; hinted_handoff_enabled=true; hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb=1024; incremental_backups=false; index_summary_capacity_in_mb=null; index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes=60; inter_dc_tcp_nodelay=false; internode_compression=all; key_cache_save_period=14400; key_cache_size_in_mb=null; listen_address=localhost; max_hint_window_in_ms=10800000; max_hints_delivery_threads=2; memtable_allocation_type=heap_buffers; native_transport_port=9042; num_tokens=256; partitioner=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner; permissions_validity_in_ms=2000; range_request_timeout_in_ms=10000; read_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; request_scheduler=org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler; request_timeout_in_ms=10000; row_cache_save_period=0; row_cache_size_in_mb=0; rpc_address=localhost; rpc_keepalive=true; rpc_port=9160; rpc_server_type=sync; saved_caches_directory=/var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches; seed_provider=[{class_name=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider, parameters=[{seeds=127.0.0.1}]}]; server_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; snapshot_before_compaction=false; ssl_storage_port=7001; sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb=50; start_native_transport=true; start_rpc=true; storage_port=7000; thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb=15; tombstone_failure_threshold=100000; tombstone_warn_threshold=1000; trickle_fsync=false; trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb=10240; truncate_request_timeout_in_ms=60000; write_request_timeout_in_ms=2000]
INFO  21:42:18 DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
INFO  21:42:18 Global memtable on-heap threshold is enabled at 59MB
INFO  21:42:18 Global memtable off-heap threshold is enabled at 59MB
INFO  21:42:19 Loading settings from file:/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
INFO  21:42:19 Node configuration:[authenticator=AllowAllAuthenticator; authorizer=AllowAllAuthorizer; auto_snapshot=true; batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb=5; batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb=1024; cas_contention_timeout_in_ms=1000; client_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; cluster_name=Test Cluster; column_index_size_in_kb=64; commit_failure_policy=stop; commitlog_directory=/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog; commitlog_segment_size_in_mb=32; commitlog_sync=periodic; commitlog_sync_period_in_ms=10000; compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec=16; concurrent_counter_writes=32; concurrent_reads=32; concurrent_writes=32; counter_cache_save_period=7200; counter_cache_size_in_mb=null; counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; cross_node_timeout=false; data_file_directories=[/var/lib/cassandra/data]; disk_failure_policy=stop; dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold=0.1; dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms=600000; dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms=100; endpoint_snitch=SimpleSnitch; hinted_handoff_enabled=true; hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb=1024; incremental_backups=false; index_summary_capacity_in_mb=null; index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes=60; inter_dc_tcp_nodelay=false; internode_compression=all; key_cache_save_period=14400; key_cache_size_in_mb=null; listen_address=localhost; max_hint_window_in_ms=10800000; max_hints_delivery_threads=2; memtable_allocation_type=heap_buffers; native_transport_port=9042; num_tokens=256; partitioner=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner; permissions_validity_in_ms=2000; range_request_timeout_in_ms=10000; read_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; request_scheduler=org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler; request_timeout_in_ms=10000; row_cache_save_period=0; row_cache_size_in_mb=0; rpc_address=localhost; rpc_keepalive=true; rpc_port=9160; rpc_server_type=sync; saved_caches_directory=/var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches; seed_provider=[{class_name=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider, parameters=[{seeds=127.0.0.1}]}]; server_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; snapshot_before_compaction=false; ssl_storage_port=7001; sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb=50; start_native_transport=true; start_rpc=true; storage_port=7000; thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb=15; tombstone_failure_threshold=100000; tombstone_warn_threshold=1000; trickle_fsync=false; trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb=10240; truncate_request_timeout_in_ms=60000; write_request_timeout_in_ms=2000]
INFO  21:42:19 JVM vendor/version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.7.0_72
INFO  21:42:19 Heap size: 246415360/247463936
INFO  21:42:19 Code Cache Non-heap memory: init = 2555904(2496K) used = 694272(678K) committed = 2555904(2496K) max = 50331648(49152K)
INFO  21:42:19 Eden Space Heap memory: init = 50331648(49152K) used = 50331648(49152K) committed = 50331648(49152K) max = 50331648(49152K)
INFO  21:42:19 Survivor Space Heap memory: init = 6291456(6144K) used = 6291456(6144K) committed = 6291456(6144K) max = 6291456(6144K)
INFO  21:42:19 CMS Old Gen Heap memory: init = 189792256(185344K) used = 846088(826K) committed = 189792256(185344K) max = 190840832(186368K)
INFO  21:42:19 CMS Perm Gen Non-heap memory: init = 21757952(21248K) used = 17329456(16923K) committed = 21757952(21248K) max = 85983232(83968K)
INFO  21:42:19 Classpath: /etc/cassandra:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/airline-0.6.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-codec-1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-math3-3.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/disruptor-3.0.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/guava-16.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/high-scale-lib-1.0.6.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.8.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/javax.inject.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jbcrypt-0.3m.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jline-1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jna-4.0.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/libthrift-0.9.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/logback-core-1.1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/lz4-1.2.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/reporter-config-2.1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snakeyaml-1.11.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snappy-java-1.0.5.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/stream-2.5.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/stringtemplate-4.0.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/super-csv-2.1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/thrift-server-0.3.7.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-thrift-2.1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/cassandra-driver-core-2.0.5.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/stress.jar::/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.8.jar
Killed`

Comment: The killed there is most likely the OOM killer shutting down the JVM as it consumes more memory than the system has available. (Linux over commits ram) Are you perhaps running on a machine with a small about of ram? If so you can try shrinking the JVM size used by C* in the cassandra-env file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Perm Gen Non-heap memory:` seems be the issue.

I would recommend you monitor the memory usage when u start cassandra (using the top command).
Modifying the Java heap size and changing the garbage collector would help you. You could refer http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_tune_jvm_c.html for tuning java parameters to see what works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra cannot be run on 512MB machines. It will get killed because of out of memory.